# window.onscroll not working in ReactJS production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm new to ReactJs and I'm encountering an issue with the **window.onscroll** function in my component. It works fine in **development mode** but fails in the **production build**, resulting in an **Internal Server Error**. This issue seems to occur only on specific pages where I'm using the **window.onscroll** function. How can I resolve this problem and ensure consistent behavior across development and **production environments**?

`This is my function`

I am using that function for some needed components.

```
let scroll = false;
let id = 0;
export const genarateUniqueId = () => {
  window.onscroll = function (e) {
    if (e.type === 'scroll') {
      scroll = true;
    }
  };
  if (!scroll) {
    id++;
    return id;
  } else if (scroll) {
    return id;
  }
};
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please add more details about the error.

Comment: Hai @Ajaz and Yogi. This function helps to return a unique id. I need to call the function only once when my component renders. When I scroll the page the function has been called so that function returns the unique id. That's why I check if the page was scrolling or not. If I scroll the page that function returns the same id so the component was re-render. This is what I expected. But this works in development mode not working in the production build.

Answer (score 0):

**Internal Server Error** looks like HTTP 500?

It's a server error, not about React issue